# Web access via Ethernet broken but Airport to same router works fine

Tags: snow-leopard, network, wifi, airport, ethernet

I've seen lots of questions asking what to do when Ethernet works and Wi-Fi doesn't, but I seem to have the opposite problem.  System details are as follows:

- 2009 Mac Mini (Intel Core Duo)
- OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)
- Fairly
  typical home network, with Centurylink ADSL service coming through an
  Actiontec DSL modem into a Buffalo wireless router/firewall/base station.
- Other computers in the house connect wirelessly to the Buffalo router which is configured to hand out IP addresses via DHCP and forward DNS requests to the DNS server (I'm using Google).  One of the Ethernet ports on the router is connected to the uplink port on a Netgear minihub, and two Macs (the Mini and an old G4 tower) are connected to that minihub.

With this setup my Mini can see the router in Network Preferences, and seems to be getting the DNS server address correctly via DHCP.  I can ping outside servers by IP address or by name and get response times under 100 ms.  Yet WWW access is incredibly slow.  Most pages that I open in Safari will take 5-10 minutes to load, if at all--usually the progress bar gets halfway through the title of the page and then just freezes.  This is a recent development (but of course I can't think of anything that might have changed to trigger it).

If I activate Airport and change the order of preferred networks in the Network Preferences pane to Airport first, Ethernet second, all of a sudden everything works fine.

I realize there is room for some hardware diagnostics to be done here.  I can take the minihub out of the equation by connecting the Mini directly to the Buffalo router, and I can try different Ethernet cables.  Beyond that I'm not sure what to do.  What can be done at the command line or via diagnostic software to see where the request packets are going and why nothing's coming back?  I'm really baffled as to why `ping` to a server by name works fine, but Safari doesn't--my limited understanding of TCP/IP says that if the former works, the latter should too.  And why does wi-fi work fine, but a hard-wired connection straight to the router doesn't?

EDIT: Here's the output of `ifconfig -v` with Airport active and Ethernet inactive.

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:25:4b:bc:f6:48 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
    lladdr 00:25:4b:ff:fe:bc:f6:48 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:25:00:f9:4c:d1 
    inet6 fe80::225:ff:fef9:4cd1%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x6 
    inet 192.168.11.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.11.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmnet8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 
    inet 192.168.186.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.186.255
vmnet1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 
    inet 192.168.37.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.37.255
```

EDIT AGAIN: Here's the `en0` section from `ifconfig -v` with Airport inactive and Ethernet active.

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:25:4b:bc:f6:48 
    inet6 fe80::225:4bff:febc:f648%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.11.200 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.11.255
    media: autoselect (10baseT/UTP <half-duplex>)
    status: active
```

EDIT #3: Here's the output from `netstat -i` for `en0` with Airport inactive and Ethernet active.

```
en0   1500  <Link#4>    00:25:4b:bc:f6:48   352450  1385   289436     0     0
en0   1500  alex-chambe fe80:4::225:4bff:   352450     -   289436     -     -
en0   1500  192.168.11    192.168.11.200    352450     -   289436     -     -
```

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `ifconfig -v` and post its output?

Comment: @jaume: Done, see above...

Comment: Thanks, I see that Ethernet is set to autonegotiate (`media: autoselect`). Could you add the output of `ifconfig -v` with Ethernet active? The `en0` section will suffice.

Comment: @jaume: Done, see above...

Comment: Thanks, that <half-duplex> may be causing the problem... Could you run `netstat -i` and add the output to your question? Only the line for `en0` is relevant. Please run `netstat -i` with Airport inactive and Ethernet active.

Comment: @jaume: OK, there were three lines starting with `en0`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, `1385` is the number of errors caused by inbound traffic, that should be zero. What is surprising is that there are no collisions nor errors for outbound traffic. Could you (try to) open a couple of websites and check the output of `netstat -i` for `en0` again? If the 2 last numbers are different than zero it could indeed be a duplex mismatch problem.

Comment: After opening and closing the Network pane in System Preferences as you suggested below (I didn't actually change any of the Advanced settings) the wired connection is now working fine... not hanging up on any web pages.  The last two numbers in `netstat -i` are still zeros.  The problem seems to have fixed itself but I don't understand why.

Comment: Weird, that almost sounds like magic... maybe opening and closing the Network pane has forced a renegotiation, and both your Mac and the minihub could successfully agree on a common, supported speed and duplex mode. Anyway, it's great it works.

Comment: I'm glad it works too but frustrated that I don't know for sure what happened.  I've given you the vote for "correct answer" regardless--at least if it happens again I will have a better idea what to look at, thanks to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an [duplex mismatch problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_mismatch): **small packets**, like the ones `ping` sends, **get through** while **large packets** (as generated when browsing the web) **get delayed or lost**, which leads to poor performance.

This problem may arise either when the autonegotiation process between your Mac Mini and the Netgear minihub fails or when speed/duplex mode are set manually and don't match at both ends.

To solve the problem you first need to check the Ethernet settings:

- Open System Preferences>Network, select Ethernet from the list on the left and click <kbd>Advanced...</kbd>.
- Select the Hardware tab.

Then:

1. If configure is set to "Automatically":

   [image]

   autonegotiation is on. Change it to "Manually" and try different Speed and Duplex settings, for example:

   [image]

   until the problem is gone. Note that you must press <kbd>OK</kbd> for the settings to take effect.
2. If configure is set to "Manually", change it to "Automatically" and test.
3. If nothing helps, try another hub or connect your Mac directly to the router. If that solves the problem replace your hub.

Comment: Thanks, sounds promising--when I have time to play with this later today I will do so and report back.